# bird in Spanish: ave, pájaro

Tags: vocabulario

I have translated bird into Spanish. There are two translations there: "ave" "pájaro".

I am studying the difference between them.

ave = "Animal vertebrado, ovíparo, de respiración pulmonar y sangre de temperatura constante, pico córneo, cuerpo cubierto de plumas, con dos patas y dos alas aptas por lo común para el vuelo, y que, en estado embrionario, tiene amnios y alantoides." - RAE

pájaro = "m. y f. Ave, especialmente si es pequeña." or "Persona astuta y con muy pocos escrúpulos." or "perdigón (‖ perdiz macho para reclamo)." or "m. coloq. pene." - RAE

hypothesis number one: "Pajaro is a small bird like hummingbirds or robins Ave is any bird in general but you use it more with big ones like eagles or owls" - Spanish guy

What is the difference?

Thank you.